# Is there a way to create a small scale dev database from Prod DB?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I was wondering if there is a way of creating a dev DB i.e. with the same schema as production database but with way less data , in PostgreSQL.

Comment: http://jailer.sourceforge.net/ promises that it can do that, but I have never used it.

Comment: Well it is a good tool.Helps understand associations in a very simple manner. Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name